# Convolution problem

Tags: convolution

This will be maybe quite easy fore somebody but I am not sure how to solve it. If I have a signal which is equal to

$$
y(n)=x(n)\star g(n), \quad n\in[0,1,...,N]
$$
where $\star$ is convolution operator, how do I get expression for taking every $K^{\textrm{th}}$ sample of $y(n)$, i.e., $y(Kn)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I get expression for taking every Kth sample of y(n), i.e., y(Kn)?

What I understand from this is you want a **notation** that represents $y[Kn]$ as a **convolution** operator. That doesn't exist. Or I cant remember.

For example the notation: $$y[Kn] = x[Kn]*g[n]$$ is **wrong**.

The following is **wrong** either: $$y[Kn] = x[Kn]*g[Kn]$$

Fundamentally $y[Kn]$ is defined as the **samples** of $y[n]$ as: $$y[Kn] = y[n]|_{n=Kn} = \sum{x[k]g[Kn-k]}$$

This last sum **cannot** be defined in a compact and simple manner by using the base signals $x[n]$,$g[n]$ and **convolution** operator alone. Rather the preferred way is to define $y[n] = x[n]*g[n]$ and indicate $y[Kn]$ to be used explicitly.

I strongly suggest you to look at the books and papers on the **multirate signal processing** subject in which such operations are abundant and some exclusive notation might have been inrtoduced so far.